# Does Firebase support one realtime database that stores and updates datas from different authorised users?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Let's imagine one application installed on 10 android devices, each one has about 4-6 different users. In the same time there must be one some Super User (second user type) that has an access to that database with all rights. Tell me please:

1. Is it possible to store and sync some session's information of every user in one unified realtime database using Firebase?
2. And based on the principles of safety, does Super User have to have some second application to get access to that realtime database or it's possible to create application with 2 kind of users (and their rights)?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes, that's one of the main reasons why the [Realtime Database](https://firebase.google.com/products/realtime-database/) and [Firestore(Beta)](https://firebase.google.com/products/firestore/) exist. You can store your user information in one of these databases. Get started [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/rtdb-vs-firestore).
2. Yes, it is possible to create an application with 2 types of users and different rights. You can process this on the client side (android code) and on the firebase side (to protect the database).